# Win+1 to 9 keys, only min/max first window, modifier keys for next window

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I use win+1, win+2, win+3, win+4 ..... win+9 keys fairly frequently

Is there a way to have an autohotkey to do the following?

Say I have chrome in position 9 on my taskbar.

1. If a chrome 2+ windows, WIN+9 only maximizes / minimizes 1st window in stack
2. SHIFT+WIN+2 maximizes / minimizes only the 2nd window
3. Ctrl+WIN+3 maximizes/minimizes only the 3rd window

[image]

Comment: Possibly, but we're not a "please write me a script" kind of site. Share your research, and we'll help you find out why its not working as you expect.

Comment: what do you mean by "Win+12"?

Comment: whoops i meant up until win+1..,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#If WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")

    #9:: ; maximize / minimize 1st window in array:
        If !WinExist("ahk_id " chrome_array[1])
            GoSub, Create_chrome_array  
        WinGet, WinState, MinMax, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[1]
        If WinState = -1
            WinMaximize, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[1]
        else
            WinMinimize, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[1]
    return

    +#9:: ; maximize / minimize 2nd window in array:
        If !WinExist("ahk_id " chrome_array[2])
            GoSub, Create_chrome_array  
        WinGet, WinState, MinMax, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[2]
        If WinState = -1
            WinMaximize, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[2]
        else
            WinMinimize, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[2]
    return

    ^#9:: ; maximize / minimize 3rd window in array:
        If !WinExist("ahk_id " chrome_array[3])
            GoSub, Create_chrome_array  
        WinGet, WinState, MinMax, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[3]
        If WinState = -1
            WinMaximize, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[3]
        else
            WinMinimize, % "ahk_id " chrome_array[3]
    return

#If

Create_chrome_array:
    ; Create an array, initially empty:
    chrome_array:= Object()
    ; Get ID list of all opened chrome windows:
    WinGet, ID, list, ahk_exe chrome.exe
    Loop, %id% ; retrieves each ID from the list, one at a time
    {
        this_ID := ID%A_Index%
        chrome_array.Push(this_ID) ; Append this_ID to the array
    }
return
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly. I edited "chrome.exe" into something like "anki.exe" and it works perfectly for a new application :)